# Hosting Silverlight 5 in IIS 5.1

Tags: silverlight, iis-5

I wanted to know if a Silverlight application can be hosted on IIS 5.1, because when I create a virtual directory and publish the Silverlight project and try browsing it, I get this following error:

> The web application you are attempting to access on this web server is currently unavailable.  Please hit the "Refresh" button in your web browser to retry your request.

Comment: Silverlight does not care about the web server where it is hosted. You probably have a general problem with your website.

Comment: Could be one of the .NET versions are not correctly installed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Host Silverlight in IIS:

1. Add application to: (Or make sure IIS_IUSRS has permission)

   ```
   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\[Application]
   ```
2. Add Website and point to Silverlight directory
3. Add it as an application
4. Make SURE you set the application pool to something that is capably of .Net 4

   1. Go to Application Pools on the Connection Pane
   2. Right click on the Application Pool you are using for the application
   3. Go to Basic Settings
   4. [image: Make it .Net 4 and Integrated]
5. Set the Default Document to your Silverlight page
6. Start the Web Site

Comment: Took me a few hours to do it myself the first time and I was using IIS7. 90% of the tutorials are old and use .Net 2

Comment: ya that is totally true :) even i took a lot of time to sort it out but couldn!!