# Silverlight 5 Deployment

Tags: .net, silverlight, iis, deployment, iis-5

Is it possible to host a silverlight 5 application with iis 5.1 ?
I've developed and application using

- .NET Fraemwrok 4.0
- Entity Framework
- Silverlight 5
- WCF Ria Services
- SQL Compact

I've no idea is it possible to install silverlight application with    above specifications on machine uses windows XP and IIS 5 or not.    
 If it's possible please give me helpful link or any tip should I    know .  
 P S : For now I don't have alternative option and I've to deploy my application on Windows XP . It is single user application but developed with Silverlight . 
I would be great if I could create setup application that install silverlight application on user's machine and all dependencies such as WCF Ria , EntityFramework , SQL Compact , and etc. Is this possible ? I am using Visual Studio 2012 .

Comment: How can you use VS 2012 on Windows XP? That's impossible. Except this doubt, I think what you want is doable, as all of them are supported on Windows XP.

Comment: @LexLi My development machine is Windows 7 . Windows XP is target machine.

Comment: Follow the steps from this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9190927/hosting-silverlight-5-in-iis-5-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, I think it should be possible to do so. Although I dont have IIS 5 but I have faced the same problem in IIS 6. IIS 5 and IIS 6 does not have any inbuild support for extension **.XAP** and so does not support Silverlight by default. To make it support .XAP we must have to add MIME type in IIS.

For Adding MIME types in IIS server, follow below mentioned steps:

- Click Start, select Programs, and then click Administrative Tools.click Internet Services Manager
- Right-click on the domain name and Open your Web Site properties.
- On the HTTP Headers tab click MIME Types.
- In the File Types window, click New Type to add a XAP Mime-Type and Click Ok
- Do iisreset

Comment: cause Silverlight is a client technology.